# The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

I am trying to implement firebase with xamarin.android but after downloading some nugat packages I started getting different errors and the latest one is as below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Central Directory corrupt. ---> System.IO.IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.SeekCore(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() FireBaseSolution
```

android target framework : 25

Some of installed references :

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
```

Please guide me how to resolve it. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue and also. I am not using any Xamarin.Build.Download package in my project. just using above packages you have mentioned. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was in downgrading version nuget package "Xamarin.Build.Download" to version 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Answering on an old question, but this may help others if they ended up in the same situation as me (not being allowed to modify the version of Xamarin.Build.Download), here's how I fixed it:
I deleted the folders for *C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Xamarin* and *C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache* and rebuilt my solution.

What I found was that evening using the NuGet cache clearing tool in Visual Studio, these directories remained untouched.
I can only surmise that this issue can also be caused by file corruption (I might have had a faulty network connection), and the DownloadCahe blocked attempting to get the "clean" files.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS I had to wipe all folders concerning Xamarin in "~/Library/Caches". Afterwards it would build fine.